# "Feeding off your fingers." What does this mean?

Tags: poetry

"Feeding off your fingers." What does this mean? I'm Russian and I don't know literary English, but I'm translating the famous song [*Come Undone* by Duran Duran](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/duranduran/comeundone.html).

> Who do you need, who do you love
>   When you come undone?
>   Who do you need, who do you love
>   When you come undone?
>
> Words, playing me deja vu
>   Like a radio tune I swear I've heard before
>   Chill, is it something real
>   Or the magic I'm feeding off your fingers?

Comment: Try providing the complete sentence/ stanza. Also a link to the source if possible. Good Luck.

Comment: The source: https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/duranduran/comeundone.html . Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, a variation of "eating out of someone's hand" (idiomatic) To behave in a docile, submissive way towards someone. Often used to describe a man's submissiveness to a woman due to romantic attraction. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eat_out_of_someone%27s_hand HTH

Comment: VTC as song lyrics are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Feed off* [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feed%20off) gaining strength due to, or streaming from/thanks to.

The whole phrase *the magic I'm feeding off your fingers* means that that the magic is coming from her[whoever is being talked to] fingers. The fingers causing the magic. [This](https://youtu.be/R4qfx3ZMSB8) is the image that comes first to my mind, but in the context of this song the hand is probably not ugly like in the video.